# HtmlUnit get element by class name containing string

Tags: java, url, web-scraping, htmlunit

I want to find any elements in the HtmlPage that have a class that contains the word 'date'.

ie i want to match any of the following:

```
<div class = 'date'> August 13 2017 </div>
<span class = 'pubDate'> August 12 2017 </div>
<div class = 'datePublished'> August 10 2017 </div>
```

In order to match exactly 'date' I am using the following:

```
HtmlPage page;
List<HtmlDivision> date = page.getByXPath("//div[@class='date']");
System.out.println(date.get(0));
```

Which is working correctly.

However, how do I change this (or what else should I use ) in order to be able to match any element that has a class name that contains the word date (case insensitive) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below XPath to match all `div` elements with attribute `class` that *contains* `"date"`:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'date')]
```

Comment: but I also want it to be case insensitive (to match 'pubDate' and the like) this does not work for those with uppercase 'date'

Comment: In this case you can try `//div[matches(@class, 'date', 'i')]` or, if your tool doesn't support `matches()`, `//div[contains(@class, 'date') or contains(@class, 'Date')]`

Comment: okay but how do I match any element ? not just div ? like any div or span or any element that has class containing date ?

Comment: `//*[matches(@class, 'date', 'i')]`